# Build a subset of OpenCV only (in particular for Android)

Tags: android, opencv

Since the OpenCV libraries according to http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android do not run on my Android phone (HTC Wildfire) -- crash when loading the libs -- I want to reduce the modules being compiled and linked into the resulting .so-library.

Does anyone know how to prevent 'make' from compiling some particular modules in OpenCV? I found the files CMakeLists.txt useful (located in every folder) that let me remove some folders from compilation but then I get stuck into dependency problems. Is it the right way to use CMakeLists.txt to exclude some folders?

In my particular case I need the cvMatchTemplate and some color conversion methods of OpenCV only. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Have you looked at these other android opencv projects: http://code.google.com/p/android-opencv/  http://billmccord.github.com/OpenCV-Android/ http://www.stanford.edu/~zxwang/android_opencv.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try! Since I only use cvMatchTemplate OpenCV version 1.1 could work just fine.

Comment: In the end I found the tutorial on http://www.stanford.edu/~zxwang/android_opencv.html very usefull. I went back to OpenCV 1.1 and successfully implemented template matching there.